# LAMP server on SuseLinux character set problem with Apache and php

Tags: php, apache2, opensuse

Hi Guys I have installed LAMP server on suse linux on Amazon. Here is the server info

Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI 1.0 (AMI Id: ami-08728661)
Amazon Linux AMI Base 1.0, EBS boot, 32-bit architecture with Amazon EC2 AMI Tools.

I am trying to pass some special charters through a URL to PHP script but am not able to get it using $_GET['data'] in php.

THIS WORKS 
localhost/test.php?data=testdata

THIS FAILS
localhost/test.php?data={testdata

so the special character "{" fails for some reason.... IS is apache or php encoding problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Url can only contain ASCII character set, so special characters can not be there. You need to urlencode you parameters.

```
$data = urlencode($data);
http://localhost/?data=$data
```

Comment: I did encode the URL, it was still failing. I was getting empty result for data soooo weird, eh? :S